# I am planning to relocate from India to Germany with my family

Tags: germany

I am planning to relocate from India to Germany with my family include my wife and 2 sons in middle school .I want to know what is the cost of living in Germany.
What should be average salary of professional at middle management.
If it is 60k Euro then is it fine?

Comment: For salaries for particular positions, such as middle management, please check something like Glassdoor.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the area where you will settle.  Bigger cities (Berlin, Munich) are extremely expensive, especially housing.  Living there on 60k per year with a family of four could be a real challenge.  But then it depends on what you expect.

On the other hand can living in the countryside be inexpensive and you can live do nicely on 60k.

To be able to give a better answer to the question some more input would be needed:

- Location?
- Housing allowance?
- Commuting allowance?
- Car provided?

Comment: -1 for (1) not checking for duplicates, (2) 60k in Berlin is an average family income and not a "real challenge", see the answers for https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/16170/51k-euros-annually-for-a-family-of-4-in-berlin-is-it-enough

Comment: Oh really?  I'd be interested to see the source for that figure.  The page you refer to does not provide one, the link there takes me to a youtub page.  https://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/in/Berlin shows that average costs without rent are about 2670 Euro/month.

And you obviously did not really read what I wrote.  I wrote in relation to Munich, Berlin that it "could be a real challenge".  That is how I expressed a possibility not a certainty.

Comment: Ok, then lets take 2670 Euro as average. Let's say one earns 60k per year (without any bonus or 13th salary), and the spouse does not work, with 2 kinds he/she will get tax class 3 and  3.396,66 Euro netto per month. + 200 Euro per child of children money (Kindergeld). In total that will be 3800 Euro netto per month. This means that they can spend 3800-2670 = 1130 Euro per month for the rent. In many areas of Berlin, this is almost (ok, maybe one needs 1300 warm, but 1130 is also doable depending on the area) enough for 3 room flat of ~75 square meters.