# I Received a Job Offer in Berlin

Tags: germany, immigration, relocation, cost-of-living, south-african-citizens

I received a job offer of 70K in berlin.  My wife is a housewife and I have 4 school going kids.  I am from South Africa.  Will we be able to live a comfortable live?  Should I take the offer?

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/16170/13223